# Trying to have a specific method executed when enter is pressed in console using while loop but instead the loop exits

Tags: java, printing, while-loop

So the method which involves 'looping' is this:

```
public static void play(World world) throws IOException {
    int userResponse = 0;
    Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
    while (userResponse != 'q') {
        world.print(w);
        System.out.println("Printed ok");
        userResponse = System.in.read();
        world = world.nextGeneration(0);
    }
}
```

and it calls the 'print' function which is here:

```
public void print(Writer w) {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(w);

    pw.println("-");
    for (int row = 0; row < cells.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < cells[0].length; col++) {
            pw.print((getCell(col, row) ? "#" : "-"));
        }
        pw.println();
    }
    pw.flush();

}
```

What should happen is that when run, the program prints the instance of 'world' [For context this is a game of life simulator] in the console, and then updates 'world'. Then on pressing enter the updated version of 'world' should be printed. When 'q' is inputted the program exits.

However what happens is that the first instance of 'world' is displayed but on pressing enter it exits the loop instead of displaying the next instance. Any glaring mistakes I've missed?

Comment: Take care, if you are using `System.in.read()`, you will get the whole line of user input. So if the user types for example the letter 'e' with a submitting return, it will return three chars: `e\r\n`. So the loop will be executed 3 times instantly after pressing return.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that, but while this is irritating its not the issue at hand really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This properly loops until I enter 'q'

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int userResponse = 0;
    while (userResponse != 'q') {
        System.out.println("Printed ok");
        userResponse = System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this also works for me too. Thank you for this, I've now identified where the problem was. It wasn't in fact exiting the loop, the problem was that nextGeneration was working incorrectly, causing an exception to be raised exiting the program. I mis-identified where the exception was being thrown.